# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 on the http://localhost:8280/services list

Tags: web-services, service, wso2, esb

Set the proxy service in WSO2 ESB 4.5.0, enter the URL in http://example.com:8280/services see a list of all the service, including the service name, method, WSDL address (admin service except), feeling that is not safe, how to shield the display?
Display the page title is "axis2: services", "Deployed services" on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The 4.7.0 version will not be displayed, but found, the same test service, call to frequency second, relatively stable in 4.5.0, but often suspended phenomenon occurred in the 4.7.0 version.